# Javascript - Use response from function

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, response, call

I am trying to develop a global function to use it more easily from another file.

At one point in my job I have this:

```
            .then(function(response) {
                if(response.data.code == 200)
                {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Modifications enregistrées !',
                        icon: 'success',

                        }).then(function() {
                            console.log(response);

                            // a parameter function which will used here
                            afterFinish();

                        });
                }
```

So in the second then (), I can access the response in console.log.

Now, I call a function that I had passed as a parameter. This function must also use the "response" attribute. Except it doesn't work.

Example :

My **afterFinish** function parameter :

```
afterFinish: function(response){
  console.log(response);
}
```

So in my main function it should give something like:

```
then(function() {
     console.log(response);

     // a parameter function which will used here
     //afterFinish function;
     console.log(response);

});
```

The 1st console.log () will send me the correct Response object. The second will return an empty Response object to me.

On the other hand, if I put the content of my afterFinish () function directly in the code instead of calling it, then necessarily I can access it.

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: You code is expecting you to pass it and you are doing `afterFinish();` so um `afterFinish(response);` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `response` into `afterFinish`:

```
afterFinish(response)
```

Accept it as a parameter in `afterFinish` (I *think* you're already this part):

```
afterFinish: function(response) {
    // ...
}
```

Live Example using `setTimeout` for asynchronousness:

```js
function fakeAjax() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(Math.random());
        }, 800);
    });
}

function myFunction(options) {
    const {afterFinish} = options;
    fakeAjax()
    .then(response => {
        afterFinish(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // ...handle/report eror...
    });
}

console.log("Running...");
myFunction({
    afterFinish: function(response) {
        console.log(`Response is ${response}`);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes it works, thank you very much ! I had tried this solution which seemed logical to me, except that I also added the response property in the then, hence the fact that it did not work. Thank you !